# Parse --- file not found

Tags: ios, ios7, cocoapods, parse-server, pffile

As I got back on working on a project that I had left for a few months, I got an error.

On this line of code:

```
#import <Parse/PFFile.h>
```

The compiler complains with this message:

```
'Parse/PFFile.h' file not found
```

I am now using Xcode Version 10.1, and this is an Objectiv C project.

I need to use the Parse pod. But after checking with the terminal, using the command:

```
find Pods -name PFFile.h
```

I could confirm that the file PFFile.h does not even exist there.

I am somewhat confused.

Anyone has had the same issue in the past?

Comment: Try to check their documentation, check the different released versions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PFFile renamed to PFFileObject. 
You can check it [here.](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/commit/067ede187a70ce9f9959ba49d33145aee3816da0)